# Ordinary Differential Equations - Integrating Factor Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Don't understand the last part of this question:

Find the value of $y_0$ for which the solution of the initial value problem:

$$y'-y=1+3\sin t , \ \ y(0)=y_0$$

remains finite as $t\to \infty$.

Attempt: I know I have to find the general solution so using an integrating factor ($e^-t$), I figured out the general solution is:

$$y(t) = ce^t -\frac32\sin t-\frac32 \cos t-1.$$

then plugging $0$ for $t$ gives:

$$y(0) = -\frac52 + ce^t.$$

I don't know how to find the value of $y_0$ or what it really means. I understand $c$ must be 0 as $t \to \infty$ or else it will be unbounded but don't know how to follow through.

Comment: You should plug in $t=0$ to$e^t$.

Comment: I think the integrating factor is $e^{-t}$.

Comment: Also just inserting the correctly recognized $c=0$ will give one unique value at $t=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not know $y_0$, the condition $y(0) = y_0$ only give

$$ y_0 = -\frac 52 + c,$$

or $c = \frac 52 + y_0$. So the solution is

$$y(t) = \left( \frac 52 + y_0\right)e^t -\frac32\sin t-\frac32 \cos t-1.$$

Now you want to know if $y(t)$ remains finite as $t \to \infty$. The term

$$-\frac32\sin t-\frac32 \cos t-1$$

is bounded for all $t$, so the only problem occurs at the $e^t$ terms. If by $t\to \infty$ you mean positive infinity, then

$$\left( \frac 52 + y_0\right)e^t$$

is not bounded unless the coefficient is zero. That is, $y_0 = -\frac 52$.

Comment: Beautifully explained, I understand now thank you